# How can I save data that is written in a text file into mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

I have a text file which has the following data

```
  {"i":1, "j":2}
  {"k":3, "l":10}
  {"i":4, "w":30}
```

each line  represents a simple document that can be saved in mongo db

the lines can have other information as well that was just an example

my question is, is it possible to read the text file line by line and somewhat create the document represented by each line and save it in mongo db?

and if yes, how would I do it(or at least, approach it)?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The language is JAVA, sorry for not mentioning

Comment: What language? Keep in mind that documents have a 16mb limit.

Comment: if your doc with greater than 16 mb and you want to one line = one record than you can easily do it.

Comment: Hi yogesh, is there any function that supports this? or should I parse each each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this scenario

read each line from your file

and insert into mongodb

for ex.

```
db.mydata.insert({"i":1, "j":2});
```

Comment: I actually create a mongo database, then create a collection and use a BasicDBObject to put records

what type of object is db? and what class has this insert method? I tried using the insert method of the DBCollection but it gives me an error when I try to insert data like you just showed me

Comment: OK I finally got it.

I used the insert method like you suggested and parsed each line by using the parse method of the JSON class, thanks!